# Python 2.5 Windows Binaries?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.5

I need to test an issue that occurs on Windows with Python 2.5, but [the releases page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/) doesn't link to a binary for 2.5.

Is there anywhere I could find a copy?

Comment: """python.org doesn't keep binaries that old""" is a palpable nonsense; you can even get Python 1.1; see `http://www.python.org/download/releases/`

Comment: In my defense, the [2.5.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.5/), [2.4.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4.6/), [2.3.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3.7/) releases, which are the only releases linked to on the [releases page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/), do *not* include links to binaries.

Comment: get the Windows installer for 2.5.5 from http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads -- beyond a certain point, PSF will only make source releases ... but ActiveState will continue to make binary installers.

Comment: That's because they are source-only releases. The 2.5.5 link includes a link to 2.5.4, in the 3rd sentence. There's more than enough explanation on those two pages. The likelihood that the issue that you need to test occurred on 2.5.5 is how high?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's on their FTP server still, it's just the link that's gone:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5/

You'll want one of the MSI files, depending on your Windows version (32-bits or 64-bits).

Comment: Nonsense; all the links are there.

Comment: Not to the Windows binaries, though.

Comment: @Thomas - this does *not* have Windows installer for the latest security release 2.5.5

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. How strange.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveState keeps old binaries for ActivePython available on [its site](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads). The oldest version there is 2.5.5.7.

Answer (score 2):

The release page has it.

http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/

Comment: Really? Obviously I see the source links… But I can't find a link to binaries anywhere :(

Comment: … well, I'm an idiot. The only reason I might possibly have been able to miss that is that the [2.5.5 download page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.5/) doesn't have links… But… Yea, I really have no idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much of a difference between 2.5.4 and 2.5.5
and there is an msi installer in 2.5.4
http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with ActiveState distributions -- read the license carefully, they are slapping on additional terms that may affect your intended use.  I'm still looking for a windows binary of the 2.5.5 version without the additional licensing restrictions.